# how to iterate through argv through command line and C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: one file only", argv[0]);
        return (1);
    } else {
        for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
            putchar(argv[i]);
        }
    }

}
```

Say I want to print the input it takes in, for instance

```
$ gcc -Wall fileabove.c 
$ ./a.out abcdefghijlmn
abcdefghijlmn
```

Basically just prints out whatever text I put into it.

Comment: It seems that you are lying to us. `gcc -Wall` gives me interesting diagnostics that point out several problems with your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
putchar(argv[i]);
```

is incorrect, because `putchar` expects a single character (type `char`), you are passing a pointer (`char*`). It should be

```
puts(argv[i]);
```

So the correct code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: one file only\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    // no need for the else
    // you exit program anyway if argc != 2
    // makes code more readable

    puts(argv[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

If you want to print character by character:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: one file only\n", argv[0]);
        return (1);
    }

    for(size_t i = 0; argv[1][i] != '\0'; ++i)
        putchar(argv[1][i]);

    putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

**edit** changed `puts("")` to `putchar('\n')` and removed `strlen` as Jonathan Leffler mentioned in the comments.

Comment: You could avoid `strlen()` and `<string.h>` with `for (size_t i = 0; argv[1][i] != '\0'; i++)` — and `putchar('\n');` is a more direct way of putting a single newline character if you've been using `putchar()` to output the rest of the data.

Comment: @MustacheMoses: yes, it would be possible to use `printf("%s\n", argv[1]);` instead of `puts(argv[1]);`.

Comment: Of course you can, `printf("%s\n", argv[1])` is equivalent to `puts(argv[1])`. When there is no format involved, I use `puts` because it has less overhead as `printf`, because `printf` must parse the format first. What is wrong is using `printf` without format:  Don't do this: `printf(argv[1])`. If you execute your program `./a.out "breaking printf with %d"`, then `printf(argv[1])` would fail.

Comment: @Pablo thanks for the tip I never thought about that. :(

Answer (score 1):

The argument array is always in the format of first index being the called program name and the subsequent index values being the parameters in order. Because you only want one argument to process, I have simplified your code as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s usage: one file only\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    } else {
        printf("%s\n",argv[1]); //print only parameter and new line
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When the user doesn't specify one parameter, then the error pops up including the program name. When the parameter is specified, it is stored in the second index of the array (index 1) and in my code, I simply printed it out using printf.

Comment: Error messages should be printed to `stderr` rather than `stdout`, but otherwise, only the indentation is less than ideal.